# inApp-Purchase Reciept iOS 6 or iOS 7 styles

Tags: ios, ios7, in-app-purchase

The application is iOS 7 + and from the server end they report that the iOS 6 style receipt is getting transmitted to them.

- How can I identify if the receipt is 6 or 7 style?
- How to create iOS 7 specific receipt? OR What setting probably I missed so my application is sending out iOS 6 receipt.

> Code

```
NSURL *receiptURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];
NSData *receipt = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:receiptURL];
if (receipt) {
    NSDictionary *requestContents = @{@"receipt-data": [receipt base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0]};
    NSLog(@"%@",requestContents);
    [self provideContentForProductIdentifier:transaction.payment.productIdentifier andPayLoad:requestContents];
}
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
```